# Android studio having fun of me with Gradle version

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have just updated Android Studio to 0.4.2, and the first time I launched it I got an error saying:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MyProject'
     Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/alex/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.8-all.zip.
     Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
```

The fun fact no. 1 is that the specified path doesn't exist - anyway, I have changed the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties in my project to 1.8, and relaunching Studio now asks for 1.9!

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**SOLUTION**

Solved this by deleting the gradle folder. It downloaded the libs and solved the dependencies on its own.

Comment: Did you delete the project's gradle folder or some other folder?

Comment: I deleted the folder containing gradle libraries

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio version 0.4.2 wont work with Gradle 1.8 you have to use gradle 1.9

Check following things :

1.inside every build.gradle file in your project the gradle dependency should look like.

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
          mavenCentral()
        }
       dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
       }
    }
```

2.If you are using Local Distribution change the path from File>Settings>Compiler>Gradle and point it to gradle 1.9.

1. Change the path in gradle-wrapper.properties to

   ```
    distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-bin.zip
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you have not read fully my question... the error was asking for the 1.8, then I set gradle to 1.8 and it was asking for the 1.9 instead of 1.8

Comment: yes but this answer i have posted because you have metioned in question that you have changed gradle wrapper to use gradle 1.8 that will never work with studio 0.4.2. Any how your problem got solved by deleting the gradle directory.